# Article under review

Tags: expressions, traduction, usage, académique, université

Comment faut-il rendre en français la structure ci-après :

> *Article under review*

J'ai rencontré plusieurs variantes mais laquelle est adéquate ?

> Article sous-revue
>
> Article en cours de revue
>
> Article en cours de review

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Article en attente de validation
```

ou

```
Article en cours d'examen
```

ou

```
Article en cours de révision
```

Comment: C'est une très bonne réponse, mais elle n'explique absolument pas les différents contextes!

Answer (score 2):

Je dirais, selon le contexte :

> article en cours de révision
>
> article en cours de relecture

Les variantes que vous citez ne sont pas correctes (*article sous-revue*) ou peu compréhensibles (*en cours de revue* n'est pas clair, et *review* ne me semble pas un anglicisme utilisé en français).

Comment: Alors en visant à un public académique (en France) est-ce mieux d'employer une de vos solutions proposées ou d'employer article en cours de review ? Cette dernière-ci, c'était un collègue natif de l'université qui m'a proposée. Or, comme vous, je l'ai trouvée un anglicisme.

Comment: @dimitris : Il vaut mieux utiliser une des solutions proposées par Greg, de préférence la première. "Article en cours de review" semble vraiment incorrect.

Comment: @dimitris Si vous envisagez de garder review, gardez donc "under review"... mais les 2 propositions faites ici me semblent bien meilleures sans faire appel à un anglicisme.

Comment: Je pense qu'il serait bon de donner un exemple pour chacune afin d'expliciter un peu le "selon le contexte". Pour moi "en cours de révision" implique un plus fort potentiel de changement : "Revoir un article", c'est le corriger, lui apporter des modifications. "Relire un article" est plutôt orienté "s'assurer que tout est correct". Mais je peux me tromper, d'où ma suggestion :-)

Comment: "Article en cours de review"? What is this language?